# How to create a running and triggering API-integration?

Tags: c#, web-services, api

I got two separate systems, each with it's own API. When the client do changes in system 2, it should trigger my code, which uses the API from both systems to transfer and save the changes to system 1. This should go both ways.

I'm using C# to achieve this.

What would you call an integration like this, and how can I make it always running so it gets triggered each time the client do changes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your original question. What have you tried so far. Please come up with a real question that contains the problem.

Comment: This is my question. If you got an answer, please bring me in the right direction :) I have done nothing till now - I need a direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many possible answers here,

Sounds like you need a service that's invoked on each client action per each system, WCF may be one option for implementation.

Here is some links that may be useful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33995/Getting-Started-with-WCF

So assuming you had a WCF Service with two exposed methods

```
Method1()
{
   UpdateSys2()
}
Method2()
{
   UpdateSys1()
}
```

You could do something like:

```
On client Action in System 1
--> Invoke Method1()

On client Action in System 2
--> Invoke Method2()
```

Answer (score 1):

In any case, I would keep both systems completely separated. This will keep both systems loosely coupled, because as you know, less dependencies = less complexity, easier maintenance etc.

You could implement a syncservice to which you publish change events from the two existing systems. Based on these events, synchronizations tasks are initiated which take care of doing the changes.

To initiate these tasks, a scheduler (like Quartz.NET) can be used to periodically check for new events, because you probably don't want to execute the changes in parallel; or you can also put a queue in between.